# py2neo multiple relationships between nodes

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, py2neo

Now assume that there are 2 nodes (A, B).

Can I create the multiple relationships between these 2 nodes?

For instance,

```
Relationship(A,"neighborhood",B) 
Relationship(A,"cooccurence",B) 
Relationship(A,"experimental",B)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple relationships by either directly using the function py2neo library or running a cypher query. Check the following for Cypher query:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()
graph.cypher.execute("""merge (A:node_a {property:{state if there is a property}})
                    merge (B:node_b {property:{state if there is a property}})
                    merge (A)-[:neighborhood]->(B)
                    merge (A)-[:cooccurence]->(B)
                    merge (A)-[:experimental]->(B)""")
```